# Can't seem to get sscanf() to work the way I want

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using AT commands for a program I'm making and am having trouble parsing them using the sscanf() function.

For instance, if I take this command:

```
"AT\r\r\nOK\r\n"
```

I want to:
* On the first call, get only the "AT" part, throw away the following "\r" character and know how many characters have been read up to that point.
* On the second call, get only the "OK" part, throw away the "\r\n" characters that come before and after the "OK" string and know how many characters have been read up to that point.

I wrote the following sscanf function call:

```
index = 0;
sscanf(buffer + index, "%*[\r\n]%[^\r]\r%*[\n]%n", new_buffer, &count);
index += count;
```

Why won't it return the strings I requested? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyse the format:

```
sscanf(buffer + index, "%*[\r\n]%[^\r]\r%*[\n]%n", new_buffer, &count);
```

First, an initial sequence of `'\r'` or `'\n'` characters are skipped (`%*[\r\n]`). Then the following characters until the next `'\r'` are scanned and stored into `new_buffer` (`%[^\r]`).

Next, all following whitespace characters are skipped (`\r`). The part up to the `'O'` of `"OK"` has been consumed now.

Then, all characters until the next newline are ignored (`%*[^\n]`). You are now left with only the final newline not consumed. Then the number of consumed characters is stored in `count`.

Your problem is that any whitespace in a format string (outside character sets, of course) consumes the entire sequence (possibly empty) of whitespace characters appearing in that place. The `\r` in the format string does not mean "one character `'\r'`", it means "all whitespace here".

You could fix it (if your format is rigid) by making it scan (and ignore) any character (which in your case is guaranteed to be a `'\r'` if your input is really what you expect.

```
sscanf(buffer + index, "%*[\r\n]%[^\r]%*c%*[\n]%n", new_buffer, &count);
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the help.
I disagree with some of the things you wrote though. I agree with the first paragraph you wrote. But, in the second paragraph, I don't think that (\r) makes the function skip all following whitespace characters. It just makes it skip a single \r character. It's like writing: sscanf(buffer,"%*[^:]:", that would only make it skip a single ':' character, not all of them.
Then I added the (%*[^\n]) part since some of the command lines end with "\r" and some end with "\r\n", and I wanted to skip both.

Comment: The problem is that the %n in the end of the token puts a 0 in count, and nothing at all is read into new_buffer.

Comment: Ok, I tested it again and I agree with what you said.. It does treat '\r' characters differently than ':' characters. The question is, how can I fix it?
For example, in this text:

    "AT\r\r\nOK\r\n"

I want it to read the "AT\r" the first time and the "\r\nOK\r\n" the second time. How can I separate the '\r' from the '\r\n' that follow it?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you want and gave. Let's assume the input buffer contains exactly `"AT\r\r\nOK\r\n"`. If you want the "AT" stored and the following `'\r'` consumed but not stored, ignoring one character - `%*c` - would do it. If you want `"AT\r"` stored, a field-width could give you that. That would be problematic if you want to use the exact same format string for the second scan, however. It might well be easier to write your own parsing function than to get the correct format for `sscanf` if your requirements are sufficiently complicated. What are your exact requirements?

Comment: I'm trying to create a general function that cuts the initial and final "\r\n" out of the line and then stores only the middle part, in this case, AT in the first line, OK in the second.

The thing is that sometimes there may be initial "\r\n" characters, sometimes there may not be (like in the AT case). Sometimes the line could end with only "\r", and sometimes with "\r\n".
How can I make the parser work for each line?

For a different processor, I did build my own parser, but that processor was "weaker" so I didn't want to overload it with the sscanf function.

P.S:Thanks again for the help.

Comment: The possible initial `"\r\n"` will be skipped if you use the `%s` format (stops at the next whitespace after the first non-whitespace sequence), or, if you want to scan text containing spaces, you could use `" %[^\r\n]%n"`; the initial space makes `sscanf` skip optional leading whitespace, then all characters until the next `'\r'`, `'\n'` or the terminating 0 will be read. The number of characters read will then be stored due to the `%n`, so you know the offset for scanning the next line. If you use `" %[^\r\n] %n"`, trailing spaces will be consumed too.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I ended up using the last format you stated:
    " %[^\r\n] %n"
It doesn't work exactly the way I wanted it to, but it works for what I need.

Thanks again for all the help.

By the way, I'm new in this forums system so I don't know how to mark the specific response as useful, there's no check mark next to it or anything. How do I mark it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is how `sscanf` deals with white space characters, such as carriage return and newline, and your expectations. `sscanf` is required to *ignore* (skip) preceding white space.

Another problem might be that the carriage returns never make it to your buffer. C implementations are required to map `\r\n` to `\n` on input (for text streams).

Comment: First, I'd like to thank you for the help Jens.

I don't think sscanf() treats carriage return or newline different than any normal character though..
Also, the contents make it to the buffer as I wrote them above (I've checked the buffer's contents after reading you reply).

Wonder what else it could be.. The token I'm passing to the function seems ok, right?